# Setting up jest report in gitlab ci

Tags: jestjs, gitlab-ci, jest-junit

Can you tell me how can I set up the jest-junit reporter?
Expected behavior: Appearances on the page of the merge request description of errors.
Real behavior: when it crashes, jobs are just red icons.

````
script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn add --dev jest-junit
    - yarn affected:test --ci --base=remotes/origin/master --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 5 days
    reporters:
      junit:
        - junit.xml

jest.config.ts:
{
  "reporters": [ "default", "jest-junit" ]
}
package.json: 
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "outputDirectory": "junit"
  }
} ```
// start jest > "affected:test": "nx affected:test --parallel --maxParallel=4"

What can be fixed? Thanks in advance!
````